# Creating a Dictionary Composite Key out of Every Permutation in a String[] within a String[][]

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, types, composite-key

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` that is acting as the composite key for another `Dictionary`.

I also have some `string[]` arrays that contains the necessary strings to be used as the composite key.

For example:

```
//Dictionary that will use composite key
Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, decimal> lookUpDictionary = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>, decimal>();

//The composite key dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> compositeKey = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//Array containing strings
string[] array1 = { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
string[] array2 = { "xx", "yy", "zz" };

//A container for the array of individual units
string[][] arrayOfArrays = {array1,array2};
```

I would like to make the composite key out of every possible combination pair of strings within each array.  For example, I'd like to fill the compositeKey thats a `Dictionary<string, string>` with every permutation of the array1 `string[]`...Such as:

```
aa aa
aa bb
aa cc
bb aa
bb bb
bb cc
cc aa
cc bb
cc cc
```

and for the second array:

```
xx xx
xx yy
xx zz
yy xx
yy yy
yy zz
zz xx
zz yy
zz zz
```

What I have tried is this nested loop algorithm that seems to work for getting the permutations I want in the right order.

```
Dictionary<string, string> compositeKey = new Dictionary<string, string>();

string[] array1 = { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
string[] array2 = { "xx", "yy", "zz" };

string[][] arrayOfArrays = {array1,array2};


//for every string[] in the arrayofarrays[][]
foreach(string[] array in arrayOfArrays)
{
    //for every string in each of those string[] arrays in the arrayOfArrays[][]
    foreach(string word in array)
    {
        //get every combination including itself
        foreach(string wordsPair in array)
        {
            string[] permutation = { word, wordsPair };
            Console.WriteLine(permutation[0] + permutation[1]);
            try
            {
                //compositeKey.Add(permutation[0], permutation[1]);
                //string value = compositeKey[permutation[0]];
                //Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            catch
            {

            }


        }

    }
}
```

The section within the try catch block is where I am having trouble.  I can't seem to create the `compositeKey` correctly.  Is this because of the nested loop, or am I using `dictionarys` completely wrong.

Edit:  It would seem that I am trying to use dictionary in a wrong way.  Is there any suggestion on the type of datatype that should be used here?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: A dictionary must have unique keys.  You have the same key used more than once.  So you dictionary must be Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: @jdweng I don't really want a List<string> in my composite key (or is it necessary here?). I'd like to put in two strings in the form of a composite key (Dictionary<string, string>) into a Dictionary<Dictionary<string,string>, decimal> and retrieve a decimal from it.

Comment: @jdweng I see now that I am trying to use dictionary in a way that I'm not supposed to.  Is there a different datatype that you would suggest, or a example of how to use the Dictionary<string,List<string>> method?

Comment: If you want a composite key then use KeyValuePair for the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating all possible combinations, you are looking for a *Cartesian Join*, in your case an array *with itself*. It can be easily implemented with a help of *Linq*

```
  string[] array1 = { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
  //string[] array2 = { "xx", "yy", "zz" };

  string[][] arrayOfArrays = array1
    .SelectMany(left => array1, (left, right) => new string[] { left, right })
    .ToArray();
```

Test:

```
  string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arrayOfArrays
    .Select(line => $"[{string.Join(", ", line)}]"));

  Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Outcome:

```
[aa, aa]
[aa, bb]
[aa, cc]
[bb, aa]
[bb, bb]
[bb, cc]
[cc, aa]
[cc, bb]
[cc, cc]
```

Please, notice, that you *shouldn't use* `string[]` as a *key* in a dictionary since array's implementation doesn't *override* `GetHashCode` and `Equals`:

```
   // Don't do this! Do not use string[] as a key...
   Dictionary<string[], string> demo = new Dictionary<string[], string>() {
     {new string[] {"a", "b"}, "c"},
   };

   string[] key = new string[] {"a", "b"};     

   // ... And that's the reason why:
   if (!demo.ContainsKey(key))
     Console.WriteLine("Oops!");
```

You may want to choose `Tuple<string, string>` instead:

```
  string[] array1 = { "aa", "bb", "cc" };

  Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string> dictionary = array1
    .SelectMany(left => array1, (left, right) => new Tuple<string, string>(left, right))
    .ToDictionary(item => item, 
                  item => "value for " + string.Join(" & ", item.Item1, item.Item2));

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dictionary));
```

Outcome:

```
[(aa, aa), value for aa & aa]
[(aa, bb), value for aa & bb]
[(aa, cc), value for aa & cc]
[(bb, aa), value for bb & aa]
[(bb, bb), value for bb & bb]
[(bb, cc), value for bb & cc]
[(cc, aa), value for cc & aa]
[(cc, bb), value for cc & bb]
[(cc, cc), value for cc & cc]
```